# AngularRouteJS not working in localhost:8888

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation. I'm currently testing out angularjs routing abilities with angular-route. But when I take out the HTML snippet code out of the index.html and put it in a views folder and call it from a routeprovider it doesn't seem to work.I've checked my console and there is no errors. I'm working from MAMP for my webserver.

My NET Tab
[image]

My Console
[image]

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="customersApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weather</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,600,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module("customersApp", ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
                controller: 'CustomersController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/customers.html'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });

}());
```

and Finally my customersController.js

```
(function(){
    var CustomersController = function ($scope){
        $scope.sortBy = 'name';
        $scope.reverse = false;
        $scope.customers = [
            {
                joined: "2004-12-24", 
                name: "Charles", 
                city: "Fairfax", 
                orderTotal: "124.45"
            },
            {
                joined: "2023-09-12", 
                name: "Donte", 
                city: "Altamonte Springs", 
                orderTotal: "5.9943"
            },
            {
                joined: "2013-01-25", 
                name: "Jelon", 
                city: "Waldorf", 
                orderTotal: "100"
            }
        ],
        $scope.doSort = function(propName){
            $scope.sortBy = propName;
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        };
    };
    angular.module("customersApp").controller("CustomersController", ['$scope',CustomersController]);
}());
```

Comment: Most instances of *"doesn't seem to work"* are accompanied by an error message. Check your browser's console

Comment: nothing is coming up in my console. It just shows a blank page.

Comment: What about debugging? Try putting some breakpoints in your controller to make sure it even gets called. Also, check your browser's *Net* console to see if it makes a request for your template and what the response is.

Comment: Just check the Net console and it's not pulling in the HTML file.

Comment: @PhilI just added images of my console and my net tab. Sorry if I'm not giving lots of information. I've been at this for 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: I see a lot of 304 responses there. Tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Just cleared the cache and updated the image. Could it be that I'm working on localhost:8888?

Comment: Nope, that should not be a problem. I suggest you open up each JS file via URL (eg `http://localhost:8888/path/to/app/controllers/customersController.js`) and make sure the contents look correct (including the modification I suggested in my answer)

Comment: @Phil I'm so sorry man. It actually was your first answer. With angular.module("customersApp").controller("CustomersController", ['$scope',CustomersController]). I was editing the wrong files. I'm so sorry. It's been a long day. Thanks for your help. If you want to accept your answer I can if you put it back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably this in `customersController.js`

```
angular.module("customersApp", [])
```

Get rid of the second argument as it recreates the module. It should be

```
angular.module('customerApp').controller(...
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module#usage

Comment: @Donte'Trumble You're not being very helpful with this *"didn't / doesn't work"* stuff. If your code has changed, update your question. Have you tried stepping through with your browser's debugger yet?